# Changing column properties in SQL Server database in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, ssms

When I want to change column properties of an existing table in an SQL Server Express 2008 R2 database via the SQL Server Management Studio Express - it doesn't let me.

I can view the properties but they're all grayed out and I don't find anything to ungray it. I've just migrated from Access and I'm wondering whether this just isn't possible (there's already data in the table - I can however delete and create new columns) or whether I'm missing something.

Comment: see that it's helpful and resolve this problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121884/sql-server-2008-cannot-insert-new-column-in-the-middle-position-and-change-dat

Comment: see that it's useful and resolved my problem 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121884/sql-server-2008-cannot-insert-new-column-in-the-middle-position-and-change-dat

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click the table and choose "Design" instead of expanding the columns, right clicking the column and choosing "Properties".